# How do I prove that the primitive element of a field extension are this way.

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field, primitive-roots

I'm doing an introductory course of field theory and there is one excercise that as easy as it seems it bring me on my nerves. It states:

Let $α_1, \dots, α_n ∈ \mathbb{C}$ be the roots of an irreducible polynomial $f ∈ Q[x]$ of degree $n ≥ 2$.

(a) Prove that there exist infinitely many tuples $(c_2,\dots , c_n) ∈ \mathbb{Z}^{n−1}$
such that
$α_1 + c_2α_2 + \dots+ c_nα_n$
is a primitive element of the splitting field of $f$ over $Q$.

(b) Check that $α_1 + α_2 + \dots + α_n$ is never a primitive element of the splitting field of
$f$ over $Q$.

Comment: Welcome to math SE, please show your own efforts in tackling this question.

Comment: I know for example that the primitive element of Q[third root of 2, second root of 2) is the sum of both, but I dont know how to generalizate it to the rest.

Comment: The second part b) is trivial as sum of roots lies in $\mathbb{Q} $ and hence can't act as a primitive element.

Comment: The first part is a consequence of the usual primitive element theorem. I hope your textbook covers it.

Comment: My textbook in fact covers the primitive element theorem, but it only states that that extesion must be simple ( because is finite and separable) but it doesn't say anithing about how to find that primitive element.

Comment: Proof of the primitive element theorem usually gives a way (in theory) to find the primitive element.

Comment: Thus for example in your case the field $\mathbb{Q} (\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ can be written as $\mathbb{Q} (\alpha_1+c_2\alpha_2)$ and the theoretical mechanism to find a suitable $c_2$ gives us infinitely many choices for $c_2$.